# Incipit of chapter VI of Neukirch's ANT book.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, adeles

The title of the chapter VI of the neukirch's ANT is "Global class field theory", and the first few lines are the following:

[image]

the author doesn't explain what is $K$ here, but from the previous definitions it seems that $K$ has to be a **number field**. So, with this restriction we are not considering all global fields but only the finite extensions of $\mathbb Q$. Why doesn't the author give the definition of adele for any global field? Is it an arbitrary choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adeles and idèles can be defined for any global field. See e.g. chapter 2, "Global Fields", of Cassels-Fröhlich's book "Algebraic Number Theory" , Academic Press, 1967

Comment: I've seen the chapter that you mention. You are right, and moreover it seems that the definition is the same